# Mixing XML and java configuration

Tags: spring, spring-java-config

I am migrating an application from an XmlWebApplicationContext to a pure java configuration solution using AnnotationConfigApplicationContext. I am having a problem reusing existing xml configuration files via @ImportResource. We are using spring 3.2.11.

When I use the xml based context, beans defined in the xml files that are java configuration (@Configuration) are automatically picked up by the context and any beans they define are visible. However, when imported through @ImportResource, @Beans in the configuration objects are not created.

Here is a unit test that illustrates my problem:

XmlConfigTest.java

```
@Test
public void testAnnotationContext()
{
    AnnotationConfigApplicationContext ctx = new AnnotationConfigApplicationContext();
    ctx.register(XmlFromJava.class);
    ctx.refresh();
    assertEquals("xml value", ctx.getBean("xmlBean", String.class));
    assertEquals("nested value", ctx.getBean("nestedBean", String.class));
}

@Test
public void testXmlContext()
{
    ClassPathXmlApplicationContext ctx = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("classpath:test.xml");
    ctx.refresh();
    assertEquals("xml value", ctx.getBean("xmlBean", String.class));
    // fails here
    assertEquals("nested value", ctx.getBean("nestedBean", String.class));
}

@Configuration
@ImportResource("classpath:test.xml")
public static class XmlFromJava { }
```

NestedConfig.java

```
@Configuration
public class NestedConfig
{
    @Bean
    public String nestedBean()
    {
        return "nested value";
    }
}
```

test.xml

```
<context:annotation-config/>

<bean class="NestedConfig"/>

<bean name="xmlBean" class="java.lang.String">
    <constructor-arg value="xml value"/>
</bean>
```

I would expect the bean 'nestedBean' to exist from the NestedConfig class. testAnnotationContext() fails to load the 'nestedBean' but testXmlContext() works.

Comment: Are you certain that you defined the path correctly? That's the only reason I can think of as to why it wouldn't work.

Comment: Show us code, the exact behaviour is affected by component scan, filters, annotation-config elements etc.. Also state more clearly what exactly you want..

Comment: Avi, I'm sure the paths to the xml files are correct. Other beans from the xml files are loaded.

Comment: I guess what I'm asking is "should" this work. My example is pretty complicated so I tried to create a unit test to illustrate the problem; and now I am more confused. I can't duplicate the behavior I see in the web context with a plain  ClassPathXmlApplicationContext. From what I understand all you need to do to be able to use configuration beans in xml files is to add the '<context:annotation-config/>' maybe I am missing something fundamental. I'll update the question with my example of how I expected it to work.

Comment: I figured out why my test failed initially, for some reason the xml did not like the 'NestedConfig' class to be a inner class. Once I moved it to it's own file the xml version worked but the java config version did not.

Comment: If I upgrade spring to 4.2.0 the test works. In my case upgrading spring may not be a possibility.

Comment: The configuration inner class, in this case, needs to be `static` and you would need to use the proper syntax to reference it ie somethinlik like `Outerclass$NestedConfig`. When using a `AnnotationConfigApplicationContext` it first scans all `@Configuration` classes passed in and expects it to be done (apparently this is fixed in newer Spring versions).